# day,month cut working but hour cut causing Error in cut.default(as.character(tweet_dat$datetime), breaks = "Hour") : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

Hi am trying to cut data into monthly, weekly, daily and hourly sets using the following timestamp data

```
[1] "2015-12-31 13:54:00 AEDT" "2015-12-30 12:41:00 AEDT" "2015-12-30 07:14:00 AEDT" "2015-12-30 03:07:00 AEDT"
[5] "2015-12-30 02:27:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 17:09:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 17:07:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 16:46:00 AEDT"
[9] "2015-12-29 16:17:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 15:10:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 14:22:00 AEDT" "2015-12-29 12:17:00 AEDT"
[13] "2015-12-28 12:45:00 AEDT" "2015-12-28 11:13:00 AEDT" "2015-12-27 21:25:00 AEDT" "2015-12-27 20:25:00 AEDT"
```

I used the following to convert from factor to posixlt date format:

```
td$datetime <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(td$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

str(td)
datetime           : POSIXlt, format: "2015-12-31 13:54:00" "2015-12-30 12:41:00" "2015-12-30 07:14:00" "2015-12-30 03:07:00" ...
```

The following 3 all work fine:

```
# create a column for month time break
td$month <- as.Date(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "month"))

# create a column for weekly time break
td$week <- as.Date(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "week", start.on.monday = FALSE))

# create a column for daily time break
td$day <- as.Date(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "day"))
```

but when I do hourly, it doesn't work

```
td$hour <- as.Date(cut(as.character(td$datetime), breaks = "hour")).
I get the following error
Error in cut.default(as.character(td$datetime), breaks = "Hour") : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: No need to convert to character and date.  Try: cut(td$datetime, breaks = "hour")

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried this - it seems cutting into day, week, month works perfectly well, but cutting into hours either produces a cut by day or an error, depending on what I try. Latest I attempted is as per below: td$hour <- as.Date.character(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "hour")) then t_freq_day_hour <- table(format(td$hour2,"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")). The date time is posix ie: $ datetime : POSIXlt, format: "2015-12-31 13:54:00" "2015-12-30 12:41:00" "2015-12-30 07:14:00" "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that works and wanted to share!

```
td$hour2 <- as.POSIXct(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "hour")) #finally - a cut works
```

The key is using the POSITct to cut rather than the cut, which seems not to pick up hour granularity.

I tested it by doing an aggregate, this way:

```
td_freq_day_hour <- table(format(td$hour2,"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"))
```

and got the following counts per hour as an example:

```
                1                 2                 
27-Dec-2015 04:00 27-Dec-2015 20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is a special format for converting dates to characters and occurs after the cut, so it does not conflict with the break points. (at least not when I tested it with your code above.

`td$hour <- as.Date.character(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "hour"))`

I did not get what I thought I would get using this (never sliced time up in this manner before) but it worked without errors or NA's and it appears inline with what your code above produced when copied and pasted.

Dates & Times are the most annoying thing to mess with in R....I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much but, sorry, this didn't work for me. Here is what I did, in case I didn't understand prop.td$hour <- as.Date.character(cut(td$datetime, breaks = "hour")) then     t_freq_day_hour <- table(format(td$hour2,"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")). The date time is posix ie: $ datetime           : POSIXlt, format: "2015-12-31 13:54:00" "2015-12-30 12:41:00" "2015-12-30 07:14:00" "

Comment: I am pretty sure, that I was not following you on how you were using the data after the cuts, which is why it did not work.  Seeing how Maric's answer accomplished your desired task, mine failed because I was not trying to give the same answer. I apologize for not understanding what you wanted.

Comment: All good, appreciate your effort. I found it by searching through a few forums. You're not wrong about the datetime being a mess.